# CAN filter for STM32F446

Tags: c, can-bus

Below is my piece of code for CAN filter. I wish to accept only frames with ID of 0x102XXXXX (hexadecimal value) where X can be any number.

```
  uint32_t filter_id =   0x10200000;
  uint32_t filter_mask = 0x1fffffff;
  sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 14;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;//CAN_FILTERMODE_IDLIST;
  sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = ((filter_id << 5)  | (filter_id >> (32 - 5))) & 0xFFFF; // STID[10:0] & EXTID[17:13];
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = (filter_id >> (11 - 3)) & 0xFFF8; // EXID[12:5] & 3 Reserved bits
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = ((filter_mask << 5)  | (filter_mask >> (32 - 5))) & 0xFFFF;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = (filter_mask >> (11 - 3)) & 0xFFF8;
  sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO1;
  sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
  sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;

  if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan2, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Filter configuration Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

As per this page https://schulz-m.github.io/2017/03/23/stm32-can-id-filter/ it should work as I expected i.e. discarding other IDs except those starting with 0x102XXXXX.
But it is blocking the desired Ids also. Please tell me where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question still remain the same. Problem solved. Updated code below. I'm working with CAN Ext Ids only.

```
  uint32_t filter_id =   0x1020;
  uint32_t filter_mask = 0x1ff0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 14;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
  sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = filter_id << 3;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = filter_mask << 3;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO1;
  sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
  sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;

  if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan2, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Filter configuration Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

This filter accepts (only) messages matching the ID sequence 0x102XXXXX where X can be any number.

Comment: can you please explain why it work now , and not before ?

Comment: Code in OP is copy pasted from a website. I didn't even care to see what it does. I was just hoping that it'd work somehow. Then I referred to the datasheet DM00135183 Pg. 1044 & 1066 and got some idea on how to identify a CAN message properly and filter. For standard IDs (num << 5) and for ext IDs (num << 3) would work only on upper 16-bit part.

Comment: Can you please, add that to your Answer to make it more usefull?, if you like you can make it like; You need to refer to the datasheet and you need to ...